# how create pair combinations in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have multi dim tensor,I want create pair combination tensor according i-th dim，then create two tensor,for example，

```
 a=tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2]],
                        [[3,3],[4,4]],
                        [[5,5],[6,6]],shape=(3,2,2)) ,
```

I create pair combination according 0 dim (index is `[0,1,2]`,so pair is `(0,1),(0,2),(1,2)`,  so new tensor b’s 0 dim come from old index `[0,0,1]`, new tensor d’s 0 dim come from old index `[1,2,2]`, finished result is:

```
b=tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2]],
                        [[1,1],[2,2]],
                        [[3,3],[4,4]]],shape=(3,2,2))
c=tf.constant([[[3,3],[4,4]],
                       [[3,3],[4,4]],
                       [[5,5],[6,6]]],shape=(3,2,2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tf.gather()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[[1,1],[2,2]],
                        [[3,3],[4,4]],
                        [[5,5],[6,6]]])
pair = ((0,1),(0,2),(1,2))
pair = tf.convert_to_tensor(pair)
inds = pair[:,0]
b = tf.gather(a, inds)
inds = pair[:,1:]
c = tf.gather(a, inds)
```